# Cell Selection DataTable PRIMEFACES?

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

i have a table and i wanna click a cell and show me a dialog
but only i have rowSelect event , it is possible to do that?...

so in this case i click in a row and then show me the object values in a dialog, but i wanna click a block to show me a dialog

```
 <h:form id="frm1">
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/> 
            <p:commandButton value="List" actionListener="#{tableBean.listCars()}" update="dtCar"/>

            <p:dataTable id="dtCar" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carModel}"
                         selectionMode="single" >  

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.readModel}"
                        update=":frm1:display :frm1:growl" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />  

                <p:column id="model">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Model  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column id="year">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Year  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column id="manufacturer">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Manufacturer  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column id="color">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        Color  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"  
                                     update=":frm1:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" actionListener="#{tableBean.leer(car)}"/>                     
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable> 

            <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  
                      showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">  

                <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

                    <h:outputText value="Model:" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.model}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="Year:" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.year}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="Color:" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.color}" />  
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:dialog>  

        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primefaces doesn't provide stock support for cell selection. You need to improvise.

1. Wrap the desired cells in a panel component

   ```
      <p:column id="model">  
          <f:facet name="header">  
             Model  
          </f:facet> 
          <h:panelGrid> 
             <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
          </h:panelGrid>
       </p:column>
   ```
2. Add an `onclick` attribute to the panelGrid that will trigger the menu

   ```
       <p:column id="model">  
          <f:facet name="header">  
             Model  
          </f:facet> 
          <h:panelGrid onclick="dialog.show()"> 
             <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
          </h:panelGrid>
       </p:column>
   ```

   Where `dialog` refers to a dialog box that you would have on the same page with `widgetVar="dialog"`. You can repeat this for all the cells you're interested in