# How to make an editable cell clickable in order to open a pop-up

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have an editable table:

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" ... editable="true"></p:dataTable>
```

There is only one line in the table and I want a cell of this line to be clickable in order to open a pop-up.
I tried the solution given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120082/cell-selection-datatable-primefaces)

```
<p:column id="myColumn" headerText="name" styleClass="align-center">
   <p:cellEditor>
       <f:facet name="output">
          <h:panelGrid update="@widgetVar(infosNameFormDialog)" onClick="PF('infosNameFormDialog').show();">
             <h:outputText value="#{element.name}" />
          </h:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
           <p:inputText value="#{element.name}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

This solution has a problem: because of the h:panelGrid I have a rectangle that frames the data of the cell, which is not acceptable.

So I tried with a p:link as other solution

```
<p:column id="myColumn" headerText="name" styleClass="align-center">
   <p:cellEditor>
       <f:facet name="output">
          <p:link update="@widgetVar(infosNameFormDialog)" onClick="event.preventDefault(); PF('infosNameFormDialog').show(); event.stopImmediatePropagation();">
             <h:outputText value="#{element.name}" />
          </p:link>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
           <p:inputText value="#{element.name}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

Now I can edit the cell with any value I want and I get a link which allows to open a pop-up.
But when there is no data in the cell, there can't be any link...
And I don't have any ideas to solve this problem

I use Primefaces 5.1

Comment: Why not just remove the 'rectangle' around the cell with some css?

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea. But I am not a CSS expert

Comment: Then try to find ot how…  become an export. It is in the generated html nothing more that a table or some divs. The 'workaround' you are requesting now is way more complex